# Как улучшить код на Python(олимпиадная задачка)?

Tags: python, массивы

Есть код к олимпиадной задаче, который подходит под 5 из 9 условий. Код и условия ниже.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
n = int(input()) 
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()] 
k = 0 
x = [] 
for i in range(1, n+1): 
    if i!=n: 
        if sum(a[:i])%i==0 and sum(a[i:])%(n-i)==0: 
            l = [str(sum(a[:i])/i)]*i + [str(sum(a[i:])/(n-i))]*(n-i) 
            if l not in x: 
                k+=1 
                x.append(l) 
if sum(a)%n==0: 
    if [str(sum(a)/n)]*n not in x: 
        k+=1 
print(k)
```

Comment: на ночь глядя такие задачи не воспринимаются :) но вот получение массива чисел красивее сделать так: `a = [*map(int, input().split())]` или `a = list(map(int, input().split()))`

Comment: @Zhihar буду благодарен, если сможете помочь с утра)

Comment: Что значит улучшить? Сейчас код работает верно? Что в нём не устраивает? Времени не хватает? памяти?

Comment: Также уточните заголовок вопроса

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Основные моменты:

- set для хранения найденных решений
  даёт уникальность из коробки, теперь не нужно проверять `not in x`
- `divmod` вместо двух делений, суммы теперь тоже считаются однажды
- крайний случай(всего один участок) объединил с остальным решением `if i else (0, 0)`

```
def solve(a, n):
    variants = set();
    for i in range(n):
        left, right = a[:i], a[i:]

        l_avg, l_rem = divmod(sum(left), i) if i else (0, 0)
        r_avg, r_rem = divmod(sum(right), n - i)

        if l_rem == r_rem == 0:
            variants.add(','.join([str(l_avg)] * i + [str(r_avg)] * (n-i)))

    return len(variants)
```

Можно добавить микрооптимизаций, вроде бегущих сумм, но непонятно по каким критериям нужно «улучшать» этот код:

```
def solve(a, n):
    variants = set();
    l_sum, r_sum = 0, sum(a)
    for i in range(n):
        l_avg, l_rem = divmod(l_sum, i) if i else (0, 0)
        r_avg, r_rem = divmod(r_sum, n - i)


        if l_rem == r_rem == 0:
            # variants.add(','.join([str(l_avg)] * i + [str(r_avg)] * (n-i)))
            variants.add(f'{i}, {l_avg}, {r_avg}' if i and l_avg != r_avg else r_avg)


        l_sum += a[i]
        r_sum -= a[i]

    return len(variants)
```

> ```
> a = [10, 4, 2, 7, 5, 8, 6, 6, 15] 
> assert solve(a, len(a)) == 3
> a = [3, 5, 2, 7, 6, 4, 5, 8, 1, 7] 
> assert solve(a, len(a)) == 3
> ```

Comment: восстановил, и да, нужно ли что-то добавлять к вашему коду?(как решить проблему с empty result)

Comment: Добавить нужно ввод и вывод с вызовом функции

Comment: ввод у вас есть - первые 2 строчки в коде в вопросе. вывод: `print(solve(a, n))`

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь и простите за трату времени, первый тест пройден на 11/11, сейчас второй запущу

Comment: на втором тесте выдает 5/9, четыре раза отлетает из-за "runtime error"

Comment: Что это за тесты там у вас такие? Вслепую вряд ли удастся это починить) Алгоритм корректный и вполне оптимальный. Что за runtime error? В коде ничего опасного нет, 2 деления(с проверкой на 0 в знаменателе) и 2 сложения в цикле, память не расходуется. Мог бы предположить, что python староват(может он не понимает f-строки), но как тогда объяснить, что 5 тестов прошли?

Comment: Попробуйте поменять строку на закомментированную

Comment: Cработало, 9/9, cпасибо большое за ваши старания!